# user-owned objects can't be created using app access token with proper permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

so I'm trying to follow the docs in FB about creating and publishing custom actions

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

so I have an app with proper publish_actions permissions, I have the app access token so I try to create an object from with something similar like

("33333333/objects/app-namespace:action", "POST", array("object" => "{"title":"Chicken Enchiladas","image":"http://upload.wikimedia...", "access_token" => "LONG APP ACCES TOKEN"))

the acces token is correct, the user ID is correct, the namespace and the action is correct, an the rest of the params are correct, like I said I follow the docs, but I keep getting

(#10) Application does not have permission for this action

I wonder why???, should I only use user access token instead of the app access token, the docs mention I can use both if I have proper permissions, thanks for any help!!

Comment: have you got any luck with this problem? I am stuck with this same thing. If you got any solution, please share

Answer (score 1):

Make sure,

1. TOKEN is an "App Token" and NOT a User "Access Token".  For example, on the Graph API Explorer there are two buttons to get tokens.  One for "App Token" and one for User "Access Token".  Make sure you use "App Token".
2. POST is to "app/objects" not "33333333/objects".  You don't actually specify the app-id.  It already knows that from the token.

That should fix ya.

Answer (score 0):

Creating objects is distinct from creating actions and `'publish_actions'` permission is about the latter.

I do not know which permission you'd need for creating objects, but another solution to this problem is to inline your objects inside the actions.  I.e., you'd be posting against a URL of the form `'user_id/app_namespace:action_name'` rather than `'user_id/objects/app_namespace:object_type_name'`, while everything else stays pretty much the same.